# Left Join with Sub Query in grails?

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

How do i write below query in Grails either using criteria query or executeQuery?

```
select * from table1 as t1 left  Join(select * from table2 where id=2)as t2 On  t2.table1=t1.id ;
```

Comment: It will be more easy to help if you show your domain model.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to do this with a criteria query or HQL rather than using the SQL you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SQL, in which you query tables, GORM/Hibernate queries query domain classes. Yes, it boils down to tables, but from the Criteria, WHERE, and HQL point-of-view, it's domain classes. Which is why, as Koloritnij pointed out, knowledge of the domain model is necessary for writing the query.

### SQL vs GORM

One difference in how SQL and GORM perform joins is that SQL joins are created on-the-fly, in the SQL itself. Whereas GORM joins are predetermined by the domain class associations. This means that in HQL you cannot join to a sub-query. You can read more about such differences [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/).

### An example

That being said, using your example SQL I made an assumption about your domain model:

```
class DomainA {
}

class DomainB {
    DomainA a
}
```

In the domain model above, `DomainB` (table2) has a uni-directional [many-to-one association](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/) with `DomainA` (table1). An HQL *similar* to your SQL is as follows:

```
def hql = 'SELECT a, b FROM DomainB AS b RIGHT OUTER JOIN b.a AS a WHERE b.id = :id'
```

The HQL can be executed like this:

```
def result = DomainB.executeQuery(hql, [id: 2])
```

Comment: Basically i want to perform join on result of subquery, if i do the way u did then where clause will be performed on the result of join, I want to use where condition on both table and then want to join there reusult, something like union.

Comment: Well, unfortunately GORM/Hibernate does not support joining on sub-queries. Unions are quite different than what you demonstrated, and also not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (if you have Domain Classes with foreign key):

```
def query
query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(table2.class)
query = query.createAlias("table1", "table1Alias",  CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN, Restrictions.in( 'table1Alias.id', 'table2.id'))
Restrictions.eq( "id", 2)
```

If not, you have to use raw SQL:

```
def dataSource
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.exequteQuery("""....""")
```